# How to debug circular dependency errors in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, circular-dependency

I am merging a separate angular app ui with my MEAN js application and getting the following error in my browser console

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: $http <- $templateRequest <- $$animateQueue <- $animate <- toastr <- mvNotifier <- authInterceptor <- $http <- Auth
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/cdep?p0=%24http%20%3C-%20%24tem…0%3C-%20mvNotifier%20%3C-%20authInterceptor%20%3C-%20%24http%20%3C-%20Auth
```

Now after visiting the error page I understood what it means but I wanted to know how to debug such errors and in which services or controllers to loop for fixing such errors

[UPDATE]

So, my Auth module is like this:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('aarthikApp')
    .factory('Auth', function Auth($rootScope, $location,  $http, $q , $cookieStore, User) {
        var currentUser = {};
        if ($cookieStore.get('token')) {
            currentUser = User.get();
        }

        return {

            /**
             * Authenticate user and save token
             *
             * @param  {Object}   user     - login info
             * @param  {Function} callback - optional
             * @return {Promise}
             */
            login: function (user, callback) {
                var cb = callback || angular.noop;
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                $http.post('/auth/local', {
                    email: user.email,
                    password: user.password
                }).
                    success(function (data) {
                        $cookieStore.put('token', data.token);
                        currentUser = User.get();
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                        return cb();
                    }).
                    error(function (err) {
                        this.logout();
                        deferred.reject(err);
                        return cb(err);
                    }.bind(this));

                return deferred.promise;
            },

            /**
             * Delete access token and user info
             *
             * @param  {Function}
             */
            logout: function () {
                $cookieStore.remove('token');
                currentUser = {};
            },

            /**
             * Create a new user
             *
             * @param  {Object}   user     - user info
             * @param  {Function} callback - optional
             * @return {Promise}
             */
            createUser: function (user, callback) {
                var cb = callback || angular.noop;

                return User.save(user,
                    function (data) {
                        $cookieStore.put('token', data.token);
                        currentUser = User.get();
                        return cb(user);
                    },
                    function (err) {
                        this.logout();
                        return cb(err);
                    }.bind(this)).$promise;
            },

            /**
             * Change password
             *
             * @param  {String}   oldPassword
             * @param  {String}   newPassword
             * @param  {Function} callback    - optional
             * @return {Promise}
             */
            changePassword: function (oldPassword, newPassword, callback) {
                var cb = callback || angular.noop;

                return User.changePassword({ id: currentUser._id }, {
                    oldPassword: oldPassword,
                    newPassword: newPassword
                }, function (user) {
                    return cb(user);
                }, function (err) {
                    return cb(err);
                }).$promise;
            },

            /**
             * Gets all available info on authenticated user
             *
             * @return {Object} user
             */
            getCurrentUser: function () {
                return currentUser;
            },

            /**
             * Check if a user is logged in
             *
             * @return {Boolean}
             */
            isLoggedIn: function () {
                return currentUser.hasOwnProperty('role');
            },

            /**
             * Waits for currentUser to resolve before checking if user is logged in
             */
            isLoggedInAsync: function (cb) {
                if (currentUser.hasOwnProperty('$promise')) {
                    currentUser.$promise.then(function () {
                        cb(true);
                    }).catch(function () {
                        cb(false);
                    });
                } else if (currentUser.hasOwnProperty('role')) {
                    cb(true);
                } else {
                    cb(false);
                }
            },

            /**
             * Check if a user is an admin
             *
             * @return {Boolean}
             */
            isAdmin: function () {
                return currentUser.role === 'admin';
            },
            isBroker: function () {
                return currentUser.role === 'broker';
            },

            /**
             * Get auth token
             */
            getToken: function () {
                return $cookieStore.get('token');
            }
        };
    });
```

Would it be right that I have to remove `$http` from it as it is being used by multiple services?
am I understanding this concept correctly?

[UPDATE#2]

So, I updated my authintercepter and the auth service to this after @YOU suggested:

```
app.factory('authInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $location, $http, $q, $cookieStore, mvNotifier) {
        return {
            // Add authorization token to headers
            request: function (config) {
                config.headers = config.headers || {};
                if ($cookieStore.get('token')) {
                    config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $cookieStore.get('token');
                }
                return config;
            },

            // Intercept 401s and redirect you to login
            responseError: function (response) {
                if (response.status === 401) {
                    $location.path('/login');
                    // remove any stale tokens
                    mvNotifier.error("You don't have enough permissions for accessing this page. Please contact Site Admin for help", "Not Logged in!", true, true);
                    $cookieStore.remove('token');
                    return $q.reject(response);
                }
                else if (response.status === 403) {
                    $location.path('/login');
                    mvNotifier.error("You are forbidden from accessing this page. Please contact Site Admin for help.", "Access Forbidden", true, true);
                    $cookieStore.remove('token');
                    return $q.reject(response);
                } else if(response.status === 405) {
                    $location.path('/');
                    $cookieStore.remove('token');
                    mvNotifier.error("Invalid/Missing Credentials!", "Please Try Logging in again!", false, false);
                }
                else {
                    return $q.reject(response);
                }
            }
        };
    })
```

and my mvNotifier service is as follows -

```
angular.module('aarthikApp').service('mvNotifier', function (toastr) {
    this.warning = function (message, title, closeButton, progressBar) {
        toastr.warning(message, title, {
            closeButton: closeButton,
            progressBar: progressBar
        });
    };
    this.error = function (message, title, closeButton, progressBar) {
        toastr.error(message, title, {
            closeButton: closeButton,
            progressBar: progressBar
        });
    };
    this.success = function (message, title, closeButton, progressBar) {
        toastr.success(message, title, {
            closeButton: closeButton,
            progressBar: progressBar
        });
    };
});
```

and the error I am getting now is -

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: $http <- authInterceptor <- $http <- Auth
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/cdep?p0=%24http%20%3C-%20authInterceptor%20%3C-%20%24http%20%3C-%20Auth
```

[UPDATE#3]

After removing $http from my auth interceptor I am getting the following error-

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: $http <- $templateRequest <- $$animateQueue <- $animate <- toastr <- mvNotifier <- authInterceptor <- $http <- Auth
```

Comment: *$http* <- $templateRequest <- $$animateQueue <- $animate <- toastr <- mvNotifier <- authInterceptor <- *$http* <- Auth - most likely your Auth code has some issue.

Comment: @YOU Please go through the edit once.

Comment: that's all your Auth code? mvNotifier is not in use there?, if so, don't inject? its part of circular dependency. also it might worth to look into mvNotifier and authInterceptor too.

Comment: yes, and I have removed the mvNotifier but it still shows the same error

Comment: take a look on mvNotifier and authInterceptor.

Comment: I changed the authInterceptor and the auth service code and the error info is updated. please have a look @YOU

Comment: remove  $http from authInterceptor, also $rootScope looks like unnessary there.

Comment: After removing I am getting the following error - Uncaught Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: $http <- $templateRequest <- $$animateQueue <- $animate <- toastr <- mvNotifier <- authInterceptor <- $http <- Auth

Comment: looks like your changes are not reflected, you using some build script like grunt or gulp?

Comment: No, I just now checked in the browser sources tab that both the files have the most recent updates. I am not building these files or injecting scripts in my html using grunt

Comment: strange, but that two $http in circular is different $http actually, one is related to Auth because it should send some http request, and the other is toastr use animation, which use templates and which need $http to get template since it is not in template cache. may be legit. but I think you need to work around by loading templates in advance or trigger toastr in different $digest cycle with $timeout or something lazy. btw are you using `angular-toastr.tpls.js`?